# Dynamic SQL running way too longer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to run a dynamic SQL query that is supposed to load more than 200M records. I tried to load all the records at once but got 'System.OutOfMemory' Exception hence decided to break the time-interval into months.The following runs for more than an hour even though if I run it for just a month. I hard-coded the dates and ran it without the 'While' and it runs normally. Can someone check and let me know if there is some error in it.
 Below is my query

```
DECLARE @FromDate VARCHAR(MAX)='',
        @params nvarchar(max) = N'@StartDate Date out,@EndDate Date out,@FromDate date out,@ToDate date out',
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=’’,
        @ToDate VARCHAR(MAX)='', 
        @StartDate VARCHAR(MAX)=’’,
        @EndDate VARCHAR(MAX)=’’;

SELECT  @FromDate= DATEADD(DAY,-365, GETUTCDATE()), @ToDate =     GETUTCDATE();
SELECT @StartDate=@FromDate, @EndDate=CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,1, @FromDate) AS DATE);
SET @SQL = '
WHILE ''' + @FromDate + ''' < ''' + @ToDate + '''
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.Sales
   (
   ProductID,
   SaleDate,
   Quantity 
   )
 Select 
      ProductID,
      SaleDate,
      Quantity 
 from 
     OPENQUERY(TeraData1,''
        Select 
        PR_ID           AS   ProductID,
        SL_Date         AS   SaleDate,
        PR_QTY          AS   Quantity
    FROM
        Sales.Product
    where
SaleDate BETWEEN ' + @StartDate + 'AND '+ @EndDate + '
'')

SET  @FromDate =DATEADD(MONTH,1,'''+ @FromDate +''')
SET  @StartDate =DATEADD(MONTH,1,'''+ @StartDate +''')
SET  @EndDate =DATEADD(MONTH,1,'''+ @EndDate +''')
END’

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @params,
                @FromDate=@FromDate,
                @ToDate=@ToDate,
                @StartDate = @StartDate out,
                @EndDate = @EndDate out;
```

Comment: Why not use stored procedure/function logic instead of dynamic SQL?

Comment: @TonyDong has a point there is nothing in the syntax you are showing use that would require dynamic sql you could use regular WHILE control syntax.  And what is likley the issue though it is a little difficult to tell is that you are mixing the scope of variables between in the dynamic sql and in your control flow

Comment: And you are mixing datatypes some too which could be part of the issue

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATE

SET @FromDate = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETUTCDATE())

WHILE @FromDate < GETUTCDATE()
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.Sales
   (
      ProductID,
      SaleDate,
      Quantity 
   )
 Select 
      ProductID,
      SaleDate,
      Quantity 
 from 
     OPENQUERY(TeraData1,
       Select 
          PR_ID           AS   ProductID,
          SL_Date         AS   SaleDate,
          PR_QTY          AS   Quantity
       FROM
          Sales.Product
       where
          SaleDate >= @FromDate AND SaleDate < DATEADD(MONTH,1,@FromDate)
    )

    SET  @FromDate =DATEADD(MONTH,1,@FromDate)
END
```

It looks like you have way more variables/dates than you need and that you don't need dynamic SQL unless you are wanting to pass the linked server name or some other column dynamically.

Also stick with the appropriate datatype for the parameter instead of letting SQL infer the values you want.

Also your use of BETWEEN for the dates would have duplicated the certain dates because it would be inclusive, to fix limit 1 side of the comparison.

If you do want to do this dynamically keep the control flow in your non dynamic SQL and pass the parameter here is an example:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATE

SET @FromDate = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETUTCDATE())

WHILE @FromDate < GETUTCDATE()
BEGIN

    DECLARE @LinkedServerName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'TeraData1'
    DECLARE @ParamDef NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@FromDate DATE'
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL = '
      INSERT INTO dbo.Sales
      (
         ProductID,
         SaleDate,
         Quantity 
      )
    Select 
        ProductID,
        SaleDate,
        Quantity 
    from 
        OPENQUERY(' + @LinkedServerName + ',
          Select 
             PR_ID           AS   ProductID,
             SL_Date         AS   SaleDate,
             PR_QTY          AS   Quantity
          FROM
             Sales.Product
          where
             SaleDate >= @FromDate AND SaleDate < DATEADD(MONTH,1,@FromDate)
       )'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @PramDef, @FromDate = @FromDate

    SET  @FromDate =DATEADD(MONTH,1,@FromDate)
END
```